# What is the goal of the Hungarian fence? To deter the refugees? Reduce the rate?

Tags: european-union, immigration, hungary

I'm talking about the [Hungarian border barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_border_barrier) that has recently been built on the Hungary-Serbian borders. What is the official reason announced by the Hungarian government? Is the goal of this barrier to stop the migrants?  To control (reduce) the rate of inflow? Is the goal to deter them?  Or why does the Hungarian government also force the migrants to choose different way?

Comment: @hownowbrowncow I'm not saying wheter it is bad or good. I'm asking what were the supporting arguments.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow Apart from not answering the question, this is one-sided point of you. Of course there are also many politicans against migration and many Europeans who express solidarity. Question is, what the official reasons were.

Comment: What do you mean by "defer"? A fence doesn't defer people.

Comment: I'm guessing that defer (delay until a later time) should have been deter (make less likely).  I was already editing, so I made that change too.

Comment: @Brythan Well I really meant defer, i.e. to delay the massive float. But I don't know the original purpose, so I'm grateful for any proposals.

Comment: What's the difference between "stopping" and "deterring"?  No fence is infallible.  "isn't the protection of the Shengen just a subordination to the obsolete rules that aren't being taken seriously anyway" seems completely subjective.

Comment: @MatthewRead Well if it is impossible to protect th whole border I would be grateful just for the official attitude of the Hungarian goverment. I didn't want to say anything for or against the barrier. I don't know how to express differently the hypothesis, that these rules apply only because they were already established. If you have an idea how to clearify it, please change it.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Why do you think a fence doesn't defer people? Do you think, that the speed migration flow hasn't decreased since it's built?

Comment: *"European Union at all states mostly positively to receiving refugees"* [citation needed]

Comment: @Philipp Citation added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel the space between your question and the currently accepted answer needs to be filled, better late than never. Also it's better to answer now as tempers have somewhat settled by now around this. 
I cite Hungarian documents, but translation services do a good job on these.

The government's official reasoning can be found here [kormany.hu](https://www.kormany.hu/hu/a-miniszterelnok/hirek/akit-lerohannak-az-senkit-nem-tud-befogadni), and another legal statement worth mentioning is the [36/2015. (IX. 22.) OGY határozat](https://mkogy.jogtar.hu/jogszabaly?docid=A15H0036.OGY).

The goal of this barrier according to the latter document is to continue to develop the economy without the burden of the unbearable influx of illegal immigrants arriving in Hungary.

Not to reduce the inflow or deter them, but stopping it altogether. "On all other issues, it's only worth talking about after we've stopped the flood".

Hungary does not want to force the migrants to choose a different way, as the PM wrote "if we cannot defend our borders, Schengen could be in jeopardy". And this statement applies to all Schengen countries.

If the protection of Schengen was just a subordination to obsolete rules, and the EU was really open about its borders, then it would make sense if the rules around the borders were lifted. The official Hungarian views state that: "Immigration is also a lucrative business on which dangerous and unscrupulous criminal groups have settled."

Answer (score 8):

The Hungarian government under Viktor Orbán has repeatedly stated that they are not very pleased with the current influx of refugees and would rather prefer if those people would not exist. Unfortunately they do and European law requires Hungary to accept refugees. So claiming that the border fence would not be partially intended as a deterrent would be naïve.

However, the official purpose of the fence is to not deter refugees but to force them to enter Hungary through the official checkpoints so they can be properly registered. [Those checkpoints are overcrowded and the humanitarian situation is disastrous](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/09/17/world/europe/europe-refugee-migrant-crisis.html?_r=0), which drives many refugee to move through Croatia instead.